# Naming Excel Worksheets when Exporting SSRS without Groups

Tags: excel, ssrs-2008

I have created a handful of tables in SSRS, all with pagebreaks in between them, which successfully exports onto separate excel worksheets/tabs. The tables are not grouped. I am looking for a way to have the worksheets/tabs be automatically named when the report is exported, but can only find ways to do that when there are groups in the report. I am pretty sure this is possible, as I do have access to another report where this seems to be the case, but I can't seem to find anything on how it is being accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the tablix, make sure it is the tablix not one of the cells that is selected. You should see the cross handle in the top left.

[image]

Now in the properties panel, just edit the page name. This can either be static text or an expression.

[image]

This defines the worksheet name when exported